# use select to show and hide multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show and hide li items based on a select control.

I am using jQuery to hide and show option values now, but I also need to hide the H1 tag if no list item is present.

Also, there is one div in particular that needs to be shown for all options.

I know I need to do an .each statement but I am not sure how.

**HTML**

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectForm").change(function(event) {
        var class1= "."+this.value;
        $(".content-list li").filter(":not('"+class1+"')").hide();
        $(class1).fadeIn("slow", "linear");     
    });
});
```

Comment: It's perfectly Ok to hide ALL of the items, then show the one you want. The :not filter step is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the following should work:

```
$("#selectForm").change(function(event) {
    $(".all").hide();
    $("." + this.value).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: currently I have the .all class for the  (select one) option.

Comment: If the user chooses that, should all below divs be hidden?

Comment: I still need to remove the H1 tags if no li item is listed under that list category

Comment: I needed a way for all options to be shown without refreshing the page. (There are multiple more categories and languages not listed here)

Comment: This will show all options if the select one option is chosen

Comment: Yes, that works fines. I still need to remove the H1 tags if no list item is showing.  I don't know if that makes sense?

Comment: Well, based on the code, there should never be no item showing, right?

Comment: i guess I didn't paste in enough code. I have 4 categories with their own h1 title. I have over 50 languages. If a language is not shown for that category I would also like to hide the H1 title.

Comment: Can you add a class or ID to your `<h1>`'s

Comment: yes I can add a class to the H1 tags

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly guessed your problem here is the working example
http://jsfiddle.net/V5dQH/

I have added the following code

```
      if( $(class1).length == 0)
      {
      $(".language-list h1").hide();
      }
      else
      {
           $(".language-list h1").show();
      }
```